# Running a CoAP client on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian, networking

We are doing a project where we are going to use a Raspberry Pi as an Internet of Things, sensor network gateway. So, we've concluded that the Raspberry Pi must have a CoAP **client** application installed in order to be able to make request to sensor nodes. We have only read about people using the Pi as a CoAP **server** before, and wonder what the best way is to install a CoAP **client** on the Pi instead.

Is it easier to install Contiki on the Pi and a CoAP client after that? There seems to be many CoAP implementations for Contiki, not many for Raspbian.

Or is there a CoAP client application that is possible to run on Raspberry Pi (we have not found one)?

Answer (score 2):

Libcoap is fully suitable for Raspbian since it has a C-implementation. I am currently using it in a kinda similar project.

Kind Regards

***libcoap***: https://libcoap.net/

Comment: can you use apt-get to install it or what?

Comment: @RichardChambers I believe you need to build it from source

Answer (score 1):

You could use a lot of CoAP implementations depending on which Language you want to work with:

- [LibCoAP](http://libcoap.sourceforge.net/)
- [SMCP](https://github.com/darconeous/smcp)
- [txThings (Python)](https://github.com/siskin/txThings/)
- [CoAPthon (Python)](https://github.com/Tanganelli/CoAPthon)
- [node-coap (Node.js)](https://github.com/mcollina/node-coap)

If you need more tools use the following [Implementations for CoAP](http://coap.technology/impls.html)

If you want testing tools for CoAP using [Copper for Mozilla FireFox](http://people.inf.ethz.ch/mkovatsc/copper.php) and [smcpctl](https://github.com/darconeous/smcp)